# What do the & and | operators do in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm debugging a batch file left behind by an old employee and I've come across the line:

```
@nmake -f makefile /E 2>&1 | tee %LOGFILEPATH%
```

What does this do?
I know what `@nmake -f makefile /E` does and I know what `tee %LOGFILEPATH%` does, but I can't find anything on what the `2>&1 |` means.
Thanks

Comment: @See http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php and http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2>&1` redirects standard error to standard out.

`|` pipes the output from `nmake` into `tee`.

Answer (score 2):

`2>&1` redirects the standard error stream to standard output.

The pipe `|` redirects standard output of the first command to the standard input to the second command.

So your command, bunches all output from `nmake` and redirects it all to `tee`